# Unit Test Symfony Form DateType

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing

when unit testing a form with a dateType field, my form test will always return null for that field.

```
    public function testSubmitValidSearchFormData()
{
    // Arrange
    $date = new \DateTime('tomorrow');

    $formData = array(
        'date' => $date,
    // some other fields
    );

    $object = new SearchModel();
    $object
        ->setDate($formData['date'])
        // set some more fields

    // Act
    $form = $this->factory->create(SearchType::class);
    $form->submit($formData);

    // Assert
    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
    $this->assertEquals($object, $form->getData()); // fails, because of field 'date'

    // some more tests...


}
```

SearchType.php:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // other fields
        // ...
        ->add('date', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Finden',
            'attr' => ['formnovalidate' => true]
        ]);

    return $builder;
}
```

Any ideas, why this is the case? My TestClass does not contain any other methods. All other fields do work properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not just about `DateType` : the `submit` method doesn't handle objects, and will set such fields to `null` if an object is provided. You have to **convert them in arrays** before using this method. You MUST follow this schema :

```
[
    'attribute_1' => 'value_1',
    'attribute_2' => 'value_2',
    ...
    'attribute_n' => 'value_n',
]
```

In your exemple, to convert the date of tomorrow to the corresponding array, you can use :

```
//Get the timestamp for tomorrow
$tomorrow = time("tomorrow");

$date = [
    //Converts the previous timestamp to an integer with the value of the
    //year of tomorrow (to this date 2018)
    'year' => (int)date('Y', $tomorrow),
    //Same with the month
    'month' => (int)date('m', $tomorrow),
    //And now with the day
    'day' => (int)date('d', $tomorrow),
];

$formData = array(
    'date' => $date,
    //some other fields
);
```

Hope this helps